# Why connect a 3-phase alternator's star-point to a rectifier bridge?

Tags: three-phase, bridge-rectifier, alternator, star

I noticed while troubleshooting a Denso alternator that the stator's star point was connected to the rectifier bridge. While probing with a multimeter, I think the schematic looks something like the below:

[image]

Source: https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/69/00/8a/0b9a5d341138df/US6828703.pdf

What is the advantage of connecting the star point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if you "lose" one of the generator's windings i.e. it goes open circuit, to prevent overloading the other two windings, the star point connection could be useful. Admittedly, it will reduce the output voltage from equivalent to line voltage peak to phase voltage peak but, I believe that this prevents further overloading of the two remaining windings (and a total loss of all three windings in the generator).

Comment: It's for an aviation application, so this makes sense from the vantage of enhanced reliability.